# LiveData return null getting API response

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am getting null live-data without executing API.
when I am calling this repo function I am getting null instead of any response then after some delay, I am getting a response from API but I don't get any return value.

**BottomSheetFragment**

```
sendOTPViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SendOTPViewModel::class.java)
sendOTPViewModel.init(context)
sendOTPViewModel.setKey()
sendOTPViewModel.key.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { key ->
            LoggerUtils.E(TAG, key)
        })
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class SendOTPViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private SendOTPRepository sendOTPRepository;

    public void init(Context mContext) {
        sendOTPRepository = SendOTPRepository.getInstance(mContext);
    }

   
    public void setKey() {
        sendOTPRepository.getKey();
    }

    public LiveData<String> getKey() {

        return sendOTPRepository.getLiveData1();
    }
   
}
```

**Repo**

```
public class SendOTPRepository {

    private static SendOTPRepository sendOTPRepository;
    private final ApiInterface apiInterface;
   
    MutableLiveData<String> liveData1 = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public SendOTPRepository(Context mContext) {
   
        apiInterface = getClientNew(mContext).create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

    public static SendOTPRepository getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if (sendOTPRepository == null) {
            sendOTPRepository = new SendOTPRepository(mContext);
        }
        return sendOTPRepository;
    }

    public void getKey() {
        Observable<String> call = apiInterface.callAPIURL();
        RXJavaCaller.GetKey(call, new RXJavaCaller.OnKeyReceived() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyReceivedSuccess() {
                LoggerUtils.E("getKey", ApiConstants.KEY_SUCCESS);
                liveData1.setValue(ApiConstants.KEY_SUCCESS);
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyReceivedError(String error) {
                LoggerUtils.E("getKey", ApiConstants.KEY_ERROR);
                liveData1.setValue(null);
            }
        });

    }

    public MutableLiveData<String> getLiveData1() {
        return liveData1;
    }

}
```

`getLiveData1()` in this i am getting null response

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior.

The observer is triggered upon creation and will return null, since no data is loaded. Once the data is loaded it will be triggered again with the update.

To handle this properly add a null check in your observer:

```
sendOTPViewModel.key.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { key -> {
        if (key != null)
            LoggerUtils.E(TAG, key)
    }})
```

---

But did you check whether it's you who specifically set the value to null here?

```
        @Override
        public void onKeyReceivedError(String error) {
            LoggerUtils.E("getKey", ApiConstants.KEY_ERROR);
            liveData1.setValue(null);
        }
```